# SQL Nested transaction

Tags: sql, transactions

Need explanation for the below  query. 
While committing the outer transaction T , the row has been already deleted by nested transaction. But still the value with ID 2 is selected and displayed.

```
BEGIN TRAN T
SELECT * from tbl_types where ID=2

    BEGIN TRAN nested
       DELETE from tbl_types where ID=2
    COMMIT TRAN nested

COMMIT TRAN T
```

Comment: See [execution plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79e37/9/0), this is normal sequential order

Comment: This is about "dirty read". Consider read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840/sql-server-dirty-reads-pros-cons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *result set* from the first select *has already been sent back to the client*.

It doesn't matter what has happened since; the *next* query will find no matches for the since-deleted records.

This is simply related to statement ordering. The following, without any nested/explicit transactions, would produce the same results:

```
SELECT * from tbl_types where ID=2
DELETE from tbl_types where ID=2
```

While this would return no results:

```
DELETE from tbl_types where ID=2
SELECT * from tbl_types where ID=2
```