# Avoiding Deadlocks within SQL transaction

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following code (simplified) to access my database. I know about using statements and parameters but I shortend this to focus my problem.

```
string ConnectionString = "ConnectionStringHere";

//1. insert Transaction
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);            
SqlTransaction myTrans = myConnection.BeginTransaction();                
string sUpdate = "INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('jon','doe')";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sUpdate, myConnection, myTrans);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

//2. select from the same table
SqlConnection myConnection2 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
string sSelect = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE ID = 123";
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sSelect, myConnection2);
myDataAdapter2.Fill(dtResult); //TimeOut Exception here

//submit changes from my transaction here
myTrans.Commit();
```

In the second part I get a TimeOutExcetion because I can't access my `User` table until I commit my transaction `myTrans.Commit();` which is after that - deadlock.

My question here is - what's the best practice to avoid deadlocks here? I could avoid the Exception by making the `SELECT` part of the transaction or by setting the [IsolationLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
SqlTransaction myTrans = myConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

But I'm not sure about the usage of those. I don't have to worry about invalid data because I always select by ID.

Comment: You don't even open the connection currently, is it your real code? Use the `using`-statement

Comment: @Tim, no not real code

Comment: Current problem arises due to using separate connections. Is that your requirement?

Comment: And what happens, if you perform SELECT on the same connection? I would think you get no deadlock then.

Comment: @Arvo ok do you have a explaination why this works?

Comment: First, you haven't got deadlock, but simple lock timeout - these are different things. Second, transaction is connection-specific; your code inside transaction locks table for reads from other connections, but not from same connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you would make the `SELECT` query as part of the transaction to solve the deadlock or time out issue. Setting the `ReadUncommitted` isolation level on first sql connection `myConnection` that you have thought is also not the right approach. I see there are two possible solutions:

1. **First Solution**: Setting isolation level `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` on the transaction `myTrans` you have started will not help. If you are comfortable with dirty reads then you should actually be setting this isolation level on the second SQL connection `myConnection2` that you are establishing for firing `select` query on `User` table. To set the isolation level for the `select` query through `myConnection2` you need to use `with (nolock)` table level hint. So your query will start to look like:

   ```
   string sSelect = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ID = 123";
   ```

   You can get more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341590/how-to-set-isolation-level-on-sqlcommand-sqlconnection-initialized-with-no-trans). 
   Also, read about the consequences of dirty read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840/sql-server-dirty-reads-pros-cons) which is a side effect of using this particular isolation level.
2. **Second solution**: Default isolation level of SQL Server is `Read Committed`. So when  you start firing query through a new SQL connection using a variable named `myConnection2` it is working on `ReadCommitted` isolation level. The default behavior exhibited by `ReadCommitted` isolation level is `Blocking Read` i.e. if there are uncommitted changes on a table (which can be committed or rollbacked due to an active transaction) then your select statement on `User` table will get blocked. It will wait for the transaction to finish so that it can read the newly updated data or the original data in case of a rollback. If it doesn't do such a blocking read then it will end up doing `dirty read` which is a well known concurrency issue with databases.
   If you do not want your `SELECT` statements to get blocked and want to keep going with last committed value of a row then there is a new database level setting in SQL Server named `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`. Here is how you can change it using SQL script:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
   ```

   Quoting Pinal Dave from his article [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/07/03/sql-server-difference-between-read-committed-snapshot-and-snapshot-isolation-level/):

> If you are having problem with blocking between readers (SELECT) and
>   writers (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE), then you can enable this property
>   without changing anything from the application. Which means
>   application would still run under read committed isolation and will
>   still read only committed data.

**Note**: This is a database level setting and will affect all the transactions on your database using `READCOMMITTED` isolation level.

In my opinion you should go with first solution. Also there are few key points which you should keep in mind to avoid deadlocks in SQL Server queries. Quoting Pinal Dave from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/16/sql-server-fix-error-1205-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction/):

- Minimize the size of transaction and transaction times.
- Always access server objects in the same order each time in application.
- Avoid cursors, while loops, or process which requires user input while it is running.
- Reduce lock time in application.
- Use query hints to prevent locking if possible (NoLock, RowLock)
- Select deadlock victim by using SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need on that select.

If you need to make sure the insert has been made prior to the select, you should have both commands executed within the same transaction, or commit the insertion before you run the SELECT query.

If not, then this being SQL Server, you could either do as you said and set the isolation level to READ UNCOMMITED, or you can use the [NOLOCK table hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx), i.e.:

```
string sSelect = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE ID = 123";
```

But before you decide to do that, please read about its pros and cons in this other question:

[When should you use "with (nolock)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686724/sql-server-when-should-you-use-with-nolock)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would get deadlocks as sql server will use rowlocks by default and it's not obvious that you would like to read the same rows you've just modified.

But that said another option to go for would be using an optimistic concurrency level such as read commited snapshot isolation (RCSI) or snapshot isolation (snapshot).  This uses tempdb to store row versions which readers can access if the data in the original table is currently locked.
  With snapshot you'd have to set the transaction isolation level explicitly in each transaction in order to use it....with RCSI it is a database level setting. For more information on this topic look at [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/).